# google lookerstudio line chart not displaying all the data

Tags: looker-studio

i have a plot where the x-axis is in hours, the y-axis is in percent values. When i make the line chart plot, it only shows a limited view. you can see in the image below the x-axis goes from 0 - 4. but my data is from 0 - 500. Is there a way to display all the data in the line chart?

[image: sample plot]

I tried to look for options to display values, but couldnt find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image] In the chart STYLE panel you can add number of points. For a data set your size data studio might struggle I would suggest either R or python both of which can handle 100k+ or Power BI will do 3500 points

Comment: thats strange, i dont see this option in looker studio, seems like its cut off and i couldnt scroll down. and yes I will look into power BI. Google studio is nice for my purpose because my data is directly taken from postgresql database

Comment: @WayneWu don't use the time series graph, use the line graph one instead that will provide you with the option to change the number of points